# Angular: insert an ID to a api path

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck with this problem:
I'm trying to delete a row from a table by passing the ID of that row (i.e. record) into the path of my API. Unfortunately it isn't recognized. However, when I replace `$scope.ID`  with a hardcoded ID-number, all is working as expected.

This is my code:

```
Controller:

$scope.go = function(record) {
        $scope.ID = record.ID;
    }

    $scope.deleteRow = function() {

        $http.delete("api.php/bml/"+$scope.ID)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log('successfully deleted ID: ' + $scope.ID);
        })
    };
```

Of course in my HTML I have a TR tag with ng-click="go(record) in it.
Strange enough the right ID number is showing up in the `console.log` message!

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$scope.deleteRow = function(ID) {

    $http.delete("api.php/bml/"+ID)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log('successfully deleted ID: ' + ID);
    })
};
```

## EDIT:

```
<button ng-click="deleteRow(id)">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Too bad: the console says: 'successfully deleted ID: undefined'
The ID is not passed through in some way.

Comment: If you are not new in 'coding', than you must know, how to resolve 'undefined' variable.
You are not sending your ID. Thats whay it is 'undefined'. Please try to get your ID first. Than this code will work for you.

Comment: @Jojoseph Please look my 'edit' above. Send your Id this way.! Thanka!

Comment: Yes, this did the trick! I feel quite stupid I didn't see that for myself.....
Thanks to you, RonakP!